# What are the URLs to add to Time Screen to be able to log in replit.com account on iMac?

Tags: authentication, url, screen, whitelist, replit

I have added these 3 urls to the authorised urls on my iMac "Time Screen" settings to be able to log in on replit.com but the page stays on the log in page...
Any ideas why it is blocked?
Thanks

```
[https://replit.com][1]
[https://replit.com/~][2]
[https://replit.com/login][3]
```

---

[image]

Thank you very much, but here are all the urls I have added thanks to your advises and it keeps blocking.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong on iMac "Screen Time"?

Answer (score 0):

For Replit to work properly you need a lot more than just `replit.com` unblocked.

> To make sure Replit works for you and your students on your school network, >you need to ensure the following domains are whitelisted/unblocked:
>
> `*.replit.com` (primary domain)
>
> `*.repl.co` (where web applications built on Replit are hosted)
>
> `*.repl.it` (old domain, not actively used)
>
> `*.replitusercontent.com` (old domain, not actively used)
>
> `*.cdn.replit.com`
>
> Clients must be able to access all subdomains of the above domains. The specific hosts that clients communicate with under the above names are subject to change without notice.

According to the [Replit docs](https://docs.replit.com/teams-edu/it-administrators-toolkit).

I do recognize that it refers to students because this specific page is for the IT dept so Replit would work in their distract.